# SimpleTunnel not working - PacketTunnel Crash

Tags: ios, networkextension

UPDATE 17/11/2016:

Ok now I'm able to see in wireshark how the connection starts, but something happens in the iPhone.

When I touch the VPN button inside the SimpleTunnel app, the status changes from Disconnected to Connecting, but immediately changes back again to Disconnected and in the server I can see this message:

2016-11-16 19:12:41.033 tunnel_server[693:7087] Accepted a new connection

PacketTunnel process is crashing for some reason... Tested in:

iPad Mini iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
iPhone 5 iOS 10.1.1 (14B150)
iPhone 5s iOS 10.0.1 (14A403)

Here you can see the crash logs:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y4sd02rp6v5nc12/AADGtIfqS0dTX5fyAxDzbQlba?dl=0

I reported this problem as a bug, number
29308978

But I need to make it work to be able to do my project.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

SimpleTunnel info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html

I have this setup:

iPhone 10.1 connected through WiFi to an AP, IP 10.0.0.33.
Mac connected through ethernet to the AP, IP 10.0.0.40.

tunnel_server started and runing on port 6969.
SimpelTunnel installed and configured with server 10.0.0.40:6969

When I touch the connect button nothing happens, just change the status to connecting.

With wireshark I can't see any packet comming from the iPhone. If I try to make a ping from the iPhone to the Mac it works well.

Any ideas?? How I can debug the connecting process of SimpleTunnel?

Regards.